# Change the url's query string and keep the route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, asp.net-mvc-5.2

On a 'updates' page I have several categories 'tags' that must be clickable that will append or remove a specific tag that is in the url.

So there are several tags defined and are filled out of Umbraco, each one now has a href that have a UrlAction to a method in a controller.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("RedirectToIndex", "Blog", new { tags = tag} )"  class="filters__link @Umbraco.If(Model.IsTagActive(tag), "selected")"><i class="material-icons">local_offer</i>@tag</a></li>
```

I now have a redirect action with a hard coded url:

```
 public ActionResult RedirectToIndex(string tags)
    {

        // build the URL string here but remember what the URL was previously??

        var url = "http://localhost:4166/updates?" + "tags=" + tags;

        return Redirect(url);
    }
```

The URL string I get is a weird `'_internal/Blog/'` kind of URL which changes with each filter click (of course).

What I want to happen is that when the user clicks on a tag the url changes with the corresponding `'updates?tags=firstTag&tags=secondTag'` (basically a redirect to his own address with additional parameters) and so forth, the Index of the controller then has the corresponding 'filter' code to filter the blogs and return them with these blogs. I have to do a full reload because the model containing all the blogs are from Umbraco and I don't see a way to access this without adding a lot of (unnecessary) complicated code.

```
public ActionResult Index(RenderModel model, [FromUri]string[] tags)
        {
           //filter code is here 
            return CurrentTemplate(blogModel);
        }
```

I want a full page reload whenever the tags are clicked and the only thing I need to figure out is how to build the URL.

I have looked in adding a on click event (server side) but then I receive an error the function is not recognized.

I have a feeling there are multiple solutions for this 'issue' and I'm trying to figure out what the best option is. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement when I was building some websites containing a filter system and I wrote some extension methods to help me in the process:
Here are some examples of use:

- Want to change the values of a param (or add new params)? e.g. `localhost/index?tag=one` and you want it to become `localhost/index?tag=two&v=1` then use `Url.RouteWithSameQueryParams(new { tag = "two", v = 1 })`.
- Want to add values to a param? e.g. `localhost/index?tag=one` and you want it to become `localhost/index?tag=one&tag=two&tag=three` then use `Url.RouteWithAddedValues("tag", "two", "three")`.
- You want to remove a value of a param? e.g. `localhost/index?tag=one&tag=two` and you want it to become `localhost/index?tag=one` then use `Url.RouteWithoutValue("tag", "two")`.

Here's my extensions class:

```
public static class UrlHelperExtensions
{

    public static string RouteWithSameQueryParams(this IUrlHelper url, object routeValues)
    {
        var resultRouteValues = new RouteValueDictionary(url.ActionContext.RouteData.Values);

        foreach (var queryValue in url.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.Query)
        {
            resultRouteValues.Add(queryValue.Key, queryValue.Value);
        }

        if (routeValues == null)
            return url.RouteUrl(resultRouteValues);

        foreach (PropertyDescriptor descriptor in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(routeValues))
        {
            if (resultRouteValues.ContainsKey(descriptor.Name))
            {
                resultRouteValues[descriptor.Name] = descriptor.GetValue(routeValues);
            }
            else
            {
                resultRouteValues.Add(descriptor.Name, descriptor.GetValue(routeValues));
            }
        }

        return url.RouteUrl(resultRouteValues);
    }

    public static string RouteWithoutValue(this IUrlHelper url, string param, string value)
    {
        var resultRouteValues = new RouteValueDictionary(url.ActionContext.RouteData.Values);

        foreach (var queryValue in url.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.Query)
        {
            if (queryValue.Key.ToLower() == param)
            {
                if (value != null)
                    resultRouteValues.Add(queryValue.Key, new StringValues(queryValue.Value.Where(s => s != value).ToArray()));
            }
            else
                resultRouteValues.Add(queryValue.Key, queryValue.Value);
        }

        return url.RouteUrl(resultRouteValues);
    }

    public static string RouteWithAddedValues(this IUrlHelper url, string param, params string[] values)
    {
        var resultRouteValues = new RouteValueDictionary(url.ActionContext.RouteData.Values);

        foreach (var queryValue in url.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.Query)
        {
            if (queryValue.Key.ToLower() == param)
            {
                var vals = new List<string>(queryValue.Value);
                vals.AddRange(values);
                resultRouteValues.Add(queryValue.Key, new StringValues(vals.ToArray()));
            }
            else
            {
                resultRouteValues.Add(queryValue.Key, queryValue.Value);
            }
        }

        if (!resultRouteValues.ContainsKey(param))
        {
            resultRouteValues.Add(param, new StringValues(values));
        }

        return url.RouteUrl(resultRouteValues);
    }

}
```

Comment: curious, whether or not I'm missing something but not sure about the `IUrlHelper` and the `new StringValues`, are they both maybe for the new .Core version? This is unfortunately still an older version.

Comment: I added the appropriate version to my tags now. I left the .core tag out for a reason when asking the question.Thank you for your help though, maybe I can use this regardless.